# How to remove unattached commit from git history

Tags: git

I have been searching for sometime and can't a similar situation. I have an old repo, unshared with anyone that somehow has a dangling commit completely unattached to any orther branch. How do I remove this from the history. The commit tree looks like:

[image]

Comment: BTW, there is only a single remote specified.

Comment: Is there either a branch or a tag pointing at any of the pink or yellow commits?

Comment: No tags or branches, this repo is from 2011 and now being looked at with git version 2.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the Git garbage collector with `git-gc`.

That should remove your dangling commits, so long as there are no tags or branches pointing to any of them.

To quote the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc):

> Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository, such as compressing file revisions (to reduce disk space and increase performance) and removing unreachable objects which may have been created from prior invocations of git add.

Answer (score 1):

If a commit is truly unreachable, a log viewer won't show it in the first place.  Log viewers like `git log --graph --oneline` work by starting with some set of references—usually branches and or tags, or whatever arguments you pass on the command line, but any reference in the `refs/` namespace will do if you pass `--all`.  To get `git log --graph` to *decorate* (annotate with branch and tag names and the like) any commits that have one of these references, add `--decorate`.

Your display looks a bit like the graph display from `gitk --all`, although gitk normally decorates each referenced commit so that you can tell *why* it appears in your graph.  It also looks a bit (more) like the display from TortoiseGit or SourceTree, but I use neither of these (and rarely bother with gitk either) so I can't say how to get them to cough up the *reason* they are showing you these commits.

Note that the stash reference (used by `git stash`, named `refs/stash` can keep a series of otherwise-abandoned commits, such as those left behind by `git rebase`, alive in a repository, well past their normal recovery lifetime.  If you have old useless stashes you may need to `git stash drop` them.  The `git filter-branch` command also copies all the references it modifies, leaving the originals in `refs/originals/` (so, for instance, `refs/heads/master`, the ref-name for branch `master`, gets moved to `refs/originals/refs/heads/master` when you get a new `refs/heads/master` by filter-copying all the commits from `master`).

Besides these, the other normally-hidden references are in Git's *reflogs*, which are what keep abandoned commits around for the 30 day recovery period, and also some special reference names like `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and `FETCH_HEAD` (and of course `HEAD` itself, but that normally just contains a branch name).

When a commit chain is truly unreachable, log viewers won't show it and `git gc` will reap it.

Comment: Sounds like it might have been in an expiring reflog, then.  Whatever viewer you were using probably *should have* labeled it appropriately, so that you could *see* that, but at least it's cleaned up now. :-)

Comment: The image came from SourceTree, should have mentioned that,